# Is there a way to use GetDlgItem() to get a handle to a child object of my main window so I don't have to pass the handle as a parameter?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

To this point I have filled the list in my combo box by passing the handle through the parameter list.  But shouldn't I be able to use `GetDlgItem` to get a handle to the combobox?  If so, what do I pass to `GetDlgItem` as the handle to the parent window if the parent window is the main window?

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

        .
        .
        .
    

    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
        {

            HWND hWndCB3;


            hWndCB3 = CreateWindow(WC_COMBOBOX, TEXT(""),
                CBS_DROPDOWN | CBS_HASSTRINGS | WS_CHILD | WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL,
                40, 40, 400, 200, hWnd, (HMENU)IDC_COMBO3, hInst, NULL);

            SQL_FillLessonInfo(hWndCB3);

        }
        break;

        .
        .
        .

}

BOOL SQL_FillLessonInfo(HWND hWndCB)
{

            .
            .
            .


            SendMessage(hWndCB, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)message.c_str());

            .
            .
            .


}
```

Wanting something like...

```
HWND hWndCB = GetDlgItem(????, IDC_COMBO3);
```

...inside of `SQL_FillLessonInfo()`.

Comment: Read the remarks section of the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdlgitem) "You can use the GetDlgItem function with any parent-child window pair, not just with dialog boxes."

Comment: You'll need to pass `hWnd` (the parent window) as a parameter instead, so it's not going to save you much :)

Comment: Okay.  That was my issue.  It seemed like `hWnd` was out of scope.  So I actually have to pass it in the parameter list?  In other words, there is no reference to the main window handle that is global (unless I explicitly make a global reference)?

Comment: The window exists in a list maintained by the system, but if you want to refer to it in your code you need to store its handle somewhere (either by passing it around to functions, or in global data). (Its handle can also be found using `FindWindow` etc at any time, of course).

Comment: Okay.  So as you said, there is nothing gained.  Probably just passing that handle as I did takes the least amount of code.

Comment: Windows has no built-in concept of a "main window". For example, you have two explorer windows open, or in Excel you say "New Window". Which one is the "main" window for Explorer? Which one is the "main" window for Excel? Now, maybe the way you designed your program is that you have only one "main" window, but that's your choice, and it's therefore your responsibility to keep track of it.

Comment: I mean the window generated using the base class that is the highest level parent window for the application.  Not sure of any other way to word it.

Comment: I consider the question answered by Jonathan Potter's comments.  I just reworded the question to make it more useful and so that his comments would fit as the logical answer to the question.

Comment: "the window generated using the base class that is the highest level parent window for the application". And what if there are two instances of that class, and each one created a window, neither of which is higher than the other? (Say the two windows are side-by-side.) Which one is the "main" one and which one is the "impostor"? At any rate, Windows doesn't know what your internal class hierarchy is, so it can't help you there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You'll need to pass hWnd (the parent window) as a parameter instead, so it's not going to save you much :) - Jonathan Potter

> The window exists in a list maintained by the system, but if you want to refer to it in your code you need to store its handle somewhere (either by passing it around to functions, or in global data). (Its handle can also be found using FindWindow etc at any time, of course). – 
> Jonathan Potter